# psexec is not working even when it says it does

Tags: windows, cmd

i am tring to use psexec to lunch a calculator or any other program on remote computer.
the cmd says that the proccess started with PID number X but when i check it on the server it is not really starts.

any advices?.

the cmd says `calc started on XX.XXX.XX.XXX with proccess ID X`.
the procces is not really starts.

this is the cmd i use: `psexec \\IP -u user -p password calc`
i checked the task manager and the procces does not exists.
locally it's working

Comment: If it is an interactive process you may need to add `-i [session]` to actually see/use it.

Comment: even with -i -s -d it is not working..

Comment: `-s -d` do not matter (or help) here. However, the optional `session` parameter *could* matter, depending on the remote environment.

Comment: i used the `-i` it's not working

Comment: Check what `query session /server:<name>` lists for the target remote.

Comment: If you got a ProcessID then it did start.

Comment: It didn’t... I checked for this PID on the remote machine from cmd with tasklist /fi and there is no such process.

Comment: @Dev93 Once psexec returned a PID, a process by that PID did start somewhere. If you don't see it, then either you are looking at the wrong machine, or the process started in the wrong session and shut down shortly after, or perhaps some policy/antivirus/etc kicked in and terminated it.

Comment: If it didn't start then it doesn't have a PID. It has a PID therefore it started. `Calc` is a starter app for old programs that starts the Windows Calculator app. `Calc` started even if it didn't do what you wanted. `Calculator://` is the shell way of starting calculator.